# SELECT DISTINCT INTO syntax error interbase sql

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I'm trying to make a copy of a table with only distinct values, using the following syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO :TAB_DISTINCT
FROM TAB_MAIN
```

But IB doesn't like the INTO line (builds a plan ok with that line commented)
Invalid token. Dynamic SQL Error. 
SQL error code = -104. Token unknown - line 2, char -1. INTO.

I've tried with & without the colon, also with & without an empty pre-existing TAB_DISTINCT with fields set up. but no cigar.

Anyone have any clues what dumbass syntax error i'm making here?
many thanks, Brian

Comment: Try exchanging the `INTO` and `FROM` clauses

Comment: http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a copy of a table with following statement:

```
  INSERT INTO copy_table (field1, field2, ... fieldn)
  SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, ... fieldn
  FROM source_table
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work providing copy_table is first created. Many thanks, Brian